# Basic Tkinter/GUI Questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm dirtying my hands with Python's Tkinter, specifically learning OOP for GUIs and have a few questions.

1. When constructing a class like so:

   ```
   class Keylogger(Frame):
       def __init__(self, master=None):
           frame = Frame.__init__(self, master)
           text = Text(frame, width=20, height=5)
           ...

   test = KeyLogger()
   test.mainloop()
   ```

   - What's the purpose of the default master argument being `None`? Normally I've been learning to specify a master widget like `root = Tk()`. Are there times a master widget is not needed/wanted?
   - I also noticed that I did not need to `pack()` my KeyLogger object, regardless if it had a master or not. I did not even pack the my Frame object. Why is that?
2. I then noticed that if I changed the code in my `__init__` method like so:

   ```
   def __init__(self, master=None):
       Frame.__init__(self, master) # no more assignment statement
       text = Text(self, width=20, height=5) # first constructor arg. changed
       ...

   test = KeyLogger()
   test.mainloop()
   ```

   - I now have to `pack()` my KeyLogger object, regardless if a master widget was present. What changed when I removed the assignment statement and just called `Frame.__init__()`?
   - Should I call the `pack()` method  inside `__init__()` or outside the class? It works both ways but I'm guessing there are some pros/cons.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the purpose of the default master argument being None?

There is no purpose. Every widget except the initial instance of `Tk` needs a parent widget. If the master is `None` it will  use the root window as a default, but explicit is always better than implicit so you should always explicitly set the master.

> I also noticed that I did not need to pack() my KeyLogger object, regardless if it had a master or not. I did not even pack the my Frame object. Why is that?

It is impossible to answer that. For a widget to show, something must call `pack`, `grid` or `place` (or, the widget needs to be inserted into a canvas or text widget). You must be doing one of those somewhere in code that you aren't showing us.

> I now have to pack() my KeyLogger object, regardless if a master widget was present. What changed when I removed the assignment statement and just called Frame.**init**()?

When you assign the value of `__init__` to `frame`, frame is set to `None`, meaning the text widget goes into the root window rather than in the frame you're creating. There must be code somewhere that is causing that widget to be packed, placed or gridded.

> Should I call the pack() method inside **init**() or outside the class? It works both ways but I'm guessing there are some pros/cons.

A widget (or composite widget, such as this) should never `pack` (or `grid` or `place`) itself in its parent. This produces a tight coupling -- the new class needs to know something about its parent (specifically, whether other widgets in the parent also use `pack`, `place`, or `grid`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.
Setting the master explicitly makes sense.
I realized why I didn't have to pack the Frame widget and yes, I did pack the text widget inside the frame variable which was None.
Thanks for the answers. Did not know __init__ returns None. TIL

Answer (score 0):

1.
 In this code, since **init** returns nothing, you just initialize a Text with None, like

```
 text = Text(None, width=20, height=5)
```

And you need to use `text.pack()` inside `__init__()` to make it take effect.

The master is used as master widget. The widget without it is its own master widget. That's why there are times we don't give it a master.

2.

In this code, you initialize a Text with a Frame instance by giving it a self parameter. You need to pack both inside `__init__()` and in the main process to make them both take effect. Like

```
from Tkinter import *

class KeyLogger(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
#         frame = Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
#         text = Text(frame, width=20, height=5)
        text = Text(self, width=20, height=5)
        text.pack()

test = KeyLogger()
test.pack()
test.mainloop()
```

If this helps, please confirm it as an answer so that someone else could find it quickly. Thanks!